# ExpandableListView with fixed groupView while scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using an ExpandableListView in my app and I everything is working fine.
Although, every groupView contains a large number of children and when the groupView is expanded and the children displayed, I would like the groupView to stay on top while scrolling down the list. In other words I'm looking out for a way to avoid that the groupViews and the children views are treated as a unique list when one groupView is expanded. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: did you got any solution here. I also have similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on using the ExpandableListView you might be able to have some logic that adds your view to a view above the list view altogether.

HEADER VIEW then ListView

when a user clicks the group set the header view, which sits above the list view, to the group.

Comment: Does such header view remain fixed while scrolling or would it just be another 'row' in the sublist?

NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header and footer views

Comment: yea true story, I dont think this would work in further thought. but you could add a hidden view above your list view altogether that you could set.